# ReactJS: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to play around with react's child to parent communication, i am passing three buttons which has unique ids, I want to simply display the values after increment button is clicked. On first click, every button does increment fine, however, after second click on any button it gives

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

. I am not sure what is happening after first click.

```
    let data = [
      {id: 1, value: 85},
      {id: 2, value: 0},
      {id: 3, value: 0}
    ]

    class Counter extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          counter: 1,
          data: this.props.data
        }
      }


      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps !== this.state.data) {
          this.setState({data: nextProps})
        }
      }

       handleClick(id) {
        this.props.increment(id, 
          this.state.data[id-1].value = this.state.data[id-1].value + 
          this.state.counter);
      }

      render() {
        return (
           <div>
              {data.map(data => {
                return (
                  <div key={data.id}>
                    {data.value}
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(data.id)}>+</button>
                  </div>
                )
              })}
           </div>
        )
      }

    }


    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          data
        }
      }

      onIncrement(id, newValue) {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          data: state.data[id-1].value = newValue
        }))
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
           <Counter data={this.state.data} increment={this.onIncrement.bind(this)}/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.querySelector("#root")
    )
```

Comment: bro you are trying to access undefined value here this.state.data[id-1] you need to create object of this value if you want to read value
this.state.data[id-1] = {}
then assign value

Comment: maybe use `nextProps.data` instad of `nextProps` when you setState({data:nextProps})

Comment: @ivica.moke, I tried that too, that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 1,
      data: this.props.data
    };
  }

  handleClick(id, index) {
    this.props.increment(
      id,
      (this.props.data[id - 1].value =
        this.props.data[id - 1].value + this.state.counter), index
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map((data
         , index) => {
          return (
            <div key={data.id}>
              {data.value}
              <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(data.id, index)}>+</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [{ id: 1, value: 85 }, { id: 2, value: 0 }, { id: 3, value: 0 }]
    };
  }

  onIncrement(id, newValue, index) {
    let {data} = this.state;
  data[index].value = newValue;
    this.setState({
      data
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.data)
    return (
      <div>
        <Counter
          data={this.state.data}
          increment={this.onIncrement.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

please take a look you are doing state updation in wrong way

Answer (score 1):

At this sentence:

```
this.props.increment(id, 
      this.state.data[id-1].value = this.state.data[id-1].value + 
      this.state.counter);
```

You are doing `id-1`, i think you don't need that, just `[id]`.
In case you are click button with id 1 your are trying to increment value of `1 - 1` and you haven't any data with `id 0`

Comment: Data is an array and i m pulling the index of the object and then assigning the value, if id is 1 then this.state.data[0].value means 85 right ?, so, initially it increments but after that it doesn't, I also tried with only [id] and setting back global data ids from 0 to 2 but giving the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The problematic thing in your code is this line

```
this.state.data[id-1].value = this.state.data[id-1].value + this.state.counter);
```

what exactly you want to do here ? because you have 3 index 0,1,2 and you are out of index the it's undefined and you got error mention your requirement here.

your code using state in useless manner and i just optimize your code in a good way. **Tip:** do not use state-full component where not required use function component. it's working fine and serve according to your need.

```
    const Counter = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.data.map(d => {
                return (
                    <div key={d.id}>
                        {d.value}
                        <button onClick={() => props.increment(d.id, (d.value + 1))}>+</button>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        data: [
            { id: 1, value: 85 },
            { id: 2, value: 0 },
            { id: 3, value: 0 }
        ]
    }
    onIncrement = (id, newValue) => {
        debugger
        var newdata = [...this.state.data];
        var d = { ...newdata[id - 1] };
        d.value = newValue;
        newdata[id - 1] = d;
        this.setState({ data: newdata })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Counter data={this.state.data} increment={this.onIncrement} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.querySelector("#root")
)
```

Comment: I simply want to increment values assigned to each buttons independently, I don't understand how i m going out of index, keeping this in mind, i am decrementing id to be able to be in the index 0, 1, 2 of the data array. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, you have wrongly implemented `componentWillReceiveProps` and `onIncrement` , i have corrected these two functions :

```
onIncrement(id, newValue) {
   let data = this.state.data;
   data[id-1].value = newValue;
   this.setState({data})
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.data !== this.props.data) {
      this.setState({data: nextProps.data})
    }
}
```

Also see the working demo here : https://repl.it/@VikashSingh1/TemporalReliableLanserver